# Windows 7/10 command line show running Applications/windows

Tags: windows, command-line, process, list

I know the command `tasklist` is able to show running **processes**.

What I want the **command line** to show *only* running **applications**.

Is there such a command on Windows or is there a way to get this list by build-in tasklist's filter?

**EDIT #1**

At *Windows Task Manager*, there is a tab called *Applications* (in Windows 10, it's under: *Processes* > *Apps*). How do I get that exact list of *apps* in the command line?

**EDIT #2**

What I mean by *"applications"* are basically *opened window* name. As stated in *Edit #1*, in the *Windows Task Manager* they call it *Applications* thus I used that word.

Comment: @HelpingHand Yes! I am doing my own research on the powershell get-process and right now mustered this: `powershell "gps | ? {$_.mainwindowhandle -ne 0} | select ProcessName | ft -hide"` but I like your solution more. Also thanks for the blog link, now I know how do Windows categorize the processes into 'Apps'. Please write it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To quote [Raymond Chen](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/Raymond+Chen+-+MSFT), given the following source:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20171219-00/?p=97606

> When you go to the Processes tab in Task Manager, you see the
>   processes grouped into three categories: App, Background Process, and
>   Windows Process. How does it decide which process goes into which
>   category?
>
> These are terms that Task Manager simply made up. The system itself
>   doesn't really care what kind of processes they are.
>
> If the process has a visible window, then Task Manager calls it an
>   "App".
>
> If the process is marked as critical, then Task Manager calls it a
>   "Windows Process".
>
> Otherwise, Task Manager calls it a "Background Process".

As the question is regarding "Applications" or "Apps" then we are just considering those with a visible Window.

The following Powershell commands maybe sufficient:

```
powershell "gps | where {$_.MainWindowTitle } | select Description
```

as might:

```
powershell "gps | where {$_.MainWindowHandle -ne 0 } | select Description
```

Related commands:
`powershell "gps | select *"` will provide a list of properties of a process that could be included in a filter or output.

Answer (score 0):

I can use Powershell:

```
$wd=new-object -com 'word.application'
$wd.tasks|?{$_.visible}|select name
$wd.quit()
```